# Power Series Extensions into the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working through Complex Analysis by Serge Lang, and I came across a part that I can't figure out on my own, and I was hoping that I can get help here. This is the theorem in question:

> *Theorem 3.2*: Let $f(T) = \sum a_nT^n$ be a non-constant power series, having a non-zero radius of convergence. If $f(0) = 0$, then there exists $s>0$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$ with $|z| \leq s $, and $z \neq 0$. (from page 58)

On the next page, the book claims that

> As a consequence of Theorem 3.2, we see that there exists at most one power series $$f(T) = \sum a_nT^n$$ which has a non-zero radius of convergence, and such that for some interval $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ we have $$f(x) = e^x \text{    for all } x \text{ in } [-\epsilon, \epsilon].$$
>   This proves the uniqueness of any power series extension of the exponential function to all complex numbers.

The problem I'm having is that it seems to be that there is a rather large jump in logic. To my understanding, Theorem 3.2 simply says that a power series $f(T)$ satisfying those conditions that equals $0$ at the origin has a disk around the origin such that its value at all points inside the disk is non-zero, except at the origin. It doesn't seem to say anything about the uniqueness of power series extensions. I would really appreciate some clarification on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the lemma you have to use is that if we restrict to power series having a non zero radius of convergence, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n  = 0$ on its disk of convergence if (and only if) $(a_n) = 0$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I still fail to see how there is a unique power series that represents the exponential function though. I think a better way to word my question is, why can't there be a different power series that also agrees with $f(x) = e^x$ on the entire real line, but has different values than the usual power series on other points in the plane?

Comment: it shows that there is (at most) only one power series agreeing with $e^z$ around $z=0$. for the real line part, read the lemma you wrote in this way : "if a non-constant power series converges on an open $U$, then its zeros on $U$ are isolated, so that it cannot vanish on some curve $\subset U$".

Answer (score 0):

$e^{z} = \sum \frac{z^n}{n!}$

Suppose there existed a powers series $P(x) = \sum a_n {x^n}$ that equaled $e^x$ in some interval around 0, i.e. $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ that was not equal to the power series above.

consider $Q(z) = P(z) - e^z = \sum (a_n - \frac {1}{n!}) {z^n}$.

$Q(z) = 0$ while $|z|<s\implies Q(z) = 0$, or $Q(z)$ has radius of convergence $= 0$